# Code not triggered when there is a value in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, pickadate

trigger the input field if it has a date value on page load

Here is my function,

```
$('#gameDate3').pickadate({
   format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
   selectYears: true,
   selectMonths: true,
   selectYears: true,
   selectMonths: true,
   disable: [
      true,
      [2023, 3, 14],
      [2023, 3, 15],
      [2023, 3, 18]
   ],
   'min': "14/04/2023",
   'max': "18/04/2023",
   klass: {
      infocus: 'picker__day--enabled',
      highlighted: 'picker__day--outfocus'
   },
   today: '', // buttons
   clear: '',
   close: '',
   onSet: function(event) {
      var selectedDate = event.select;
      var formattedDate = new Date(selectedDate).toLocaleDateString('en-GB'); // Convert timestamp to formatted date
      $.ajax({
         url: 'schedule_getgame.cfm?gamedate=' + formattedDate + '&clientID=' + '1111',
         success: function(data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
               var $jsonObject = $.parseJSON(data);
               $gameSelectAway.html('');
               if ($jsonObject.length === 0) {
                  $gameSelectAway.prop("disabled", true);
                  $color1.css('display', 'none');
               } else {
                  $gameSelectAway.prop("disabled", false);
                  $color1.css('display', 'inline-block');
                  $gameSelectAway.append('<option value="">Please select Game ......</option>');
                  $.each($jsonObject, function(index, item) {
                     $gameSelectAway.append("<option value='" + item.gameID + "-" + item.clientID + "-" + item.gameNumber + "-" + item.gameDate + "-" + item.gameTime + "-" + item.homeTeam + "-" + item.awayTeam + "'>" + 'Game ' + item.gameNumber + " on " + item.gameDate + " at " + item.gameTime + " between " + item.homeTeam + " and " + item.awayTeam + "</option>");
                  });
               }
            }
         }
      });
   }
})
```

now how can i trigger it on page load because in one of the case, it can have a value coming from db already populated

and in this case when the page is load, in the ajax call it populates the second select with data and value, i want to map the data from query to keep the selected one

Comment: Check if your field already contains a value after the above initialization code has run, and then use https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/#method-trigger to get the `set` handler executed ...?

Comment: i am already using, but how can i use set

Comment: What do you mean? There is an example on how to trigger the `open` callbacks right there. And you want to trigger the `set` callbacks instead ...

Comment: i read about onSet but how can i fit that in my  call above so it calls ajax and selected the value from the db

Comment: If you trigger any of these events, then it will call the callback function you specified.

Comment: i am trying offliner but i do not think i am getting what you are mentioning, eventualy

Comment: When you initialize this on a field that already has a value set, it should automatically consider that value as "selected". So all that's necessary now, is to make your AJAX request - so check if the field was already filled (_after_ the initialization of the datepicker), and if so, trigger the event. Then it should perform your AJAX request, and fill the select field.

Comment: `let picker = $('#gameDate3').pickadate(...);` And then, after you determined the field was filled on page load already, `picker.trigger('set');`

Comment: its not working, the way you mntioned, the trigger never executes